# Pass through authentication with LDAP and Kerberos

Tags: openldap, kerberos, sles, sasl

I have a SLES 12 server and installed and configured MIT KDC and openLDAP. I want to use pass through authentication in openLDAP so that the password is only stored in the KDC and I don't have to specify in the openLDAP as well.

I have been following these posts where they say to setup saslauthd.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65093/how-to-test-ldap-that-authenticates-with-kerberos

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566096/server-ldap-example-comexample-com-not-found-in-kerberos-database

However, I cant find the kerberos5 as the authentication mechanism in the list of available mechanisms which are : (getpwent pam rimap shadow ldap)

My question is why isn't my version of saslauthd 2.1.26 not showing any kerberos5 authentication mechanism?

Comment: We will need a lot more than pointer to others users questions, what is your current configuration, what did you do for testing, are your users correctly set-up in the LDAP ???

Comment: Well my question was why can't I see the kerberos 5 as the authentication mechanism in saslauthd? Do I need to install some module or plugin?